# Getting a TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: python, django

```
def post(self, request):
    form = CsvUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        with open(request.FILES['csv']) as csv_source:
            has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csv_source.read(1024))
            csv_source.seek(0)
            reader = csv.DictReader(csv_source)
            ....
            ....

    return HttpResponse("file Uploaded")
```

using the above code i am trying to upload a csv file and read it. but I am getting the following error.

> with open(request.FILES['csv']) as file:
>   TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

what am i missing here ?

django 2.0.7
python 3.5

Comment: You don't need to open it, it's already a file steam. Just pass it directly to the csv functions.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, If you can add it as an answer i could accept it . thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [`@ Daniel Roseman`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) said, you can directly use the filestream as ,

```
def post(self, request):
    form = CsvUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        reader = csv.DictReader(request.FILES['csv'])
        ....
        ....

    return HttpResponse("file Uploaded")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the request into a BytesIO stream, then perform your operations on that object.

```
def post(self, request):
    form = CsvUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        csv_source = BytesIO(request.FILES['csv'].read())
        has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csv_source.read(1024))
        csv_source.seek(0)
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_source)
        ....
        ....

    return HttpResponse("file Uploaded")
```